# Proof of the theorem of optimal approximation!

Tags: approximation-theory

I am looking at the proof of the following theorem:
$$$$
Let $\widetilde{H}$ subspace of $H$,where $H$ is an Euclidean space, and $x \in H$. $y \in \widetilde{H}$ is the optimal approximation of $x$ of $\widetilde{H}$ iff $(x,u)=(y,u) \forall u \in \widetilde{H} \text{ or } (x-y,u)=0\ \forall u \in \widetilde{H}$

I got stuck at the proof of this direction: $\Rightarrow$
$$$$
In my notes they do it like that:
$$$$
Let $y \in \widetilde{H}$ is the optimal approximation of $x$. We define $\varphi(λ)=||x-(y+λz)||^{2},z \in \widetilde{H} $
$$\varphi(λ)=||x-y||^{2}-2λ (x-y,z)+λ^2 ||z||^{2}$$
$$$$
We want to find the minimum of $\varphi(λ)$,so we find  $\varphi'(λ)=0 \Rightarrow -(x-y,z)+λ||z||^2=0 \Rightarrow λ_{min}=\frac{(x-y,z)}{||z||^2}$
$$min \varphi(λ)=\varphi(λ_{min}) < \varphi(0)=||x-y||^2$$
That can't be true,because the optimal approximation of $x$ of  $\widetilde{H}$ is $y$

Could you explain it to me?? Why do we take $\varphi(λ)$ ?What is it?? :/

Comment: That $y$ is the optimal approximation means that $\varphi$ has its global minimum (not _necessarily_ a unique minimum, consider $z = 0$) in $\lambda = 0$. A minimum is a critical point, hence $\varphi'(0) = 0$, hence ...

Comment: But..with this proof,have we shown that $(x,u)=(y,u) \forall x \in \widetilde{H} \text{ or that } (x-y,u)=0 \forall x \in \widetilde{H}$ ?

Comment: That should be $\forall u\in\widetilde{H}$. Both, $(x,u) = (y,u) \iff (x-y,u) = 0$.

Comment: But is this proven at the proof that I have written at my first post???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove that $y$ is the optimal approximation.

So suppose it is not.

Then that must mean that there is some other vector in $\tilde H$ that is a better approximation. Any vector in $\tilde H$ can be written as $y+\lambda z$ (btw, that should be a $+$ instead of a $-$). So let's suppose that vector is a better approximation.

The function $\varphi(\lambda)$ is the squared distance of $x$ to this other approximation as function of $\lambda$.
If we can prove that $\lambda$ must be zero to find the shortest squared distance, we have proven that $y$ is the optimal approximation after all.

Comment: I understand..But how can I conclude to that: $(x-y,u)=0 \forall u \in \widetilde{H} \text{ or } (x,u)=(y,u) \forall u \in \widetilde{H} $ ?

Comment: What is the definition of an optimal approximation?

Comment: If $y$ is an optimal approximation,then $(x-y,u)=0 \forall u \in \widetilde{H} \text{ and } (x,u)=(y,u) \forall u \in \widetilde{ H}$.. Right?

Comment: Isn't that what you were asking?? (Confused)

Comment: I'm confused right now.. :/ We suppose that $y \in \widetilde{H}$ is not the optimal approximation of $x \in H$ from $\widetilde{H}$. Any vector in $\widetilde{H}$ can be written as $y+ λz$. We define the function $$\varphi(λ)=||x-(y+λz)||^2=(x-(y+λz), x-(y+λz))=((x-y)-λz, (x-y)-λz)=||x-y||^2-2(x-y, -λz)+||λz||^2=||x-y||^2+2λ(x-y, z)+λ^2||z||^2$$
We want to find the minimum of $\varphi(λ)$, so we find $$\varphi '(λ)=0 \Rightarrow 2(x-y,z)+2λ||z||^2=0 \Rightarrow -(x-y,z)=λ||z||^2 \Rightarrow λ=- \frac{(x-y,z)}{||z||^2}$$
How can I continue??

Comment: Let's first go back to the definition of an optimal approximation. I suspect that it should be the point $y$ in $\widetilde H$ with the shortest distance $||x-y||$. Can it be that is it?

Comment: Substituting your $\lambda$ in $\varphi(\lambda)$ gives $\varphi(\lambda) = ||x-y||^2 + 3\frac{(x-y, z)^2}{||z||^2}$, which is always at least $||x-y||^2$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I am looking again at this proof...You told me that: $$\text{Any vector in $\tilde H$ can be written as } y+\lambda z $$

But....why is it like that?? Are $y,z$ elements of the basis of $\widetilde{H}$ ??

Comment: I like Serena! Also, how did you find that: $$\phi(\lambda)=||x-y||^2+3 \frac{(x-y,z)^2}{||z||^2}$$ ?

Comment: Could I do it maybe also like that:
$$\phi(\lambda)=||x-y||^2-2 \lambda (x-y,z)+ \lambda^2 ||z||^2$$
$$\phi'(\lambda)=2 \lambda ||z||^2-2(x-y,z)$$
$$\phi'(\lambda)=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=\frac{(x-y,z)}{||z||^2}$$
$$\text{ As } \phi''(\lambda)=2 ||z||^2 \geq 0, \phi \text{ achieves its minimum at} \lambda_{\min}=\frac{(x-y,z)}{||z||^2}$$
$$\text{ Also, as } \phi''(\lambda) \geq 0 , \phi'  \nearrow$$
$$\lambda> \lambda_{\min} \Rightarrow \phi'(\lambda)> \phi'(\lambda_{\min})=0 \Rightarrow \phi'(\lambda)>0 \Rightarrow \phi \nearrow \text{ for } \lambda>\lambda_{\min}$$

Comment: $$ \lambda_{\min} \geq 0 \Rightarrow \phi(\lambda_{\min}) \geq \phi(0)=||x-y||^2, \text{ Contradiction!!! }$$

Or can't we do it like that??

Comment: Yes. $y,z$ are elements of $\widetilde H$.

Comment: Did you try to substitute $\lambda$ in $\varphi(\lambda)$?

Comment: Both your methods look right! :)

Comment: So we can write any vector as $y+\lambda z$, because of the properties:
$$\text{ If } u, v \in H \Rightarrow u+v \in H$$
$$\text{ If } u \in H \Rightarrow c \cdot u \in H$$
?

Comment: I substituted $\lambda_{min}$ in $\phi(\lambda)$, but I don't know how to continue calculating it..

Comment: More specifically, suppose we have $u$ and $y$ in $H$, then $u = y + 1 \cdot (u-y)$.